# Create a custom button in Accounts that generates a new opportunity with products that are related to type of division

Tags: apex, visualforce

Account: The propose is to fill the fields in the related list "division"  and link to the products. I want to create a button that generate an opportunity with products that are related with division.

This is the code that i create:

[image]

Can anybody please, give me some guidelines!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I will not code it for you as it is time consuming....
But here you have some tips:

Prepare Custom Setting with mapping Acc division -> Products external Id/Name/Id - something that identify your products.

1. Chose PriceBook for your Opportunity.
2. create Opp (store its Id value as you will need it to redirect)
3. List all PriceBookEntries that match your custom setting(PBE is conected to the Product)
4. Based on PBE create Opportunity products
5. redirect to the opportunity.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Artur. I already made the code and if anyone need:

Answer (score 0):

```
 public PageReference  RedirectOpp()
    {  
      Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();    
      Account m_Account=[select Name from Account where Id =:AccountId];
      opp.AccountId = AccountId;
      opp.Name= m_Account.Name;
      opp.CloseDate= date.today();   
      Database.SaveResult ds = Database.insert(opp);
      List <OpportunityLineItem> oliList = new List <OpportunityLineItem>();
      List<String> divisoes = new List<String>();
      List<String> actividades = new List<String>();
      for(Divisoes__c div : [select divisao__c, Atividade__c from Divisoes__c where Conta__c =:AccountId ]){
        divisoes.add(div.divisao__c);
        actividades.add(div.Atividade__c);
      }
      List<PriceBookEntry> priceBookList = [select Id, UnitPrice, Product2Id,Product2.Id, Product2.Name from PriceBookEntry where Product2.Divisao__c in :divisoes AND  Product2.Atividade__c in: actividades AND PriceBook2.isStandard=true ];  
      for (PriceBookEntry pbe : priceBookList)
      {       
       OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId = ds.getId(), PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id, Quantity = 1, TotalPrice = 12*pbe.UnitPrice);
                  oliList.add(oli);  
      } 
     insert oliList; 
       return pgReturnPage;        
    }
```